# PagedList: Paginação de dados com Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

Estou utilizando o PagedList com Ajax, mas não estou conseguindo mudar de página porque quando clico no botão, que representa a página, o valor que está indo para o controller é nulo. Fiz a seguinte estrutura:

View:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<MeuProjeto.Web.ViewModels.ClienteViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
...
<div id="ClientesTableDiv">
    @Html.Partial("_ClientesTable", Model)
</div>

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagina => Url.Action("Paginacao","Cliente", pagina ), 
       PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing( 
          new AjaxOptions() { 
                              HttpMethod = "POST",
                              UpdateTargetId = "ClientesTableDiv" 
                            }))
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Paginacao(int? pagina)
{
    ...
    int numeroPagina = pagina ?? 1; // A pagina está vindo como nula.
    int tamanhoPagina = 5;

    return PartialView("_ClientesTable",
              clientesViewModel.ToPagedList(numeroPagina, tamanhoPagina));
}
```

O código da última linha da View deve ser alterado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem um ajuste a ser feito aqui:

- Está `pagina` coloque `new {pagina}`:
- Em vez de `POST`, coloque `GET`, porque nesse caso é `link`:

> `@Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagina => Url.Action("Paginacao","Cliente", new { pagina }), PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing( new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "ClientesTableDiv" }))`

- No método também mude o **verb** para `GET`

---

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult Paginacao(int? pagina)
{
    ...
    int numeroPagina = pagina ?? 1; // A pagina está vindo como nula.
    int tamanhoPagina = 5;

    return PartialView("_ClientesTable",
        clientesViewModel.ToPagedList(numeroPagina, tamanhoPagina));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio! Deu certo, mas gerou um outro problema
hehe.
No primeiro link não é gerado as mesmas configurações dos 
outros links (href, data-ajax, ...), e por isso não têm 
como solicitar ao controller.